# What did Yoda do on Dagobah?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, yoda, dagobah

Leader of the Jedi Council, Yoda was. For *centuries*, a Jedi.

To Dagobah he went. For twenty years, lived there did he. Bored, he might be.

Do what, did he?

Comment: he ate mud and buggs obvy

Comment: Sat around waiting for Luke to show up so he could refuse to teach him.  Then he got in a fight with a beeping garbage can over the worst flashlight ever made, and he lost.

Comment: Downvote this, why?

Comment: Meditated, probably.

Comment: @RogueJedi I read that as "medicated", and thought you were implying that Yoda was a junkie.

Comment: I've added a comma to the title, because I couldn't understand what you were doing without reading the question text.     I think this way is easier to get the intent.  Feel free to revert if you feel strongly, but you used the same punctuation in your final question line already.   ("Do what**,** he did?)

Comment: @Moogle Take his medications, he must. Old, he is.

Comment: I don't know that this is canon any longer, but I recall an EU book where they suggest Yoda uses Dagobah to hide.  Apparently it has a strong dark side presence (or something), and that clouds and conceals his own presence in the force, which keeps the Sith from tracking him down.

Comment: Do what, did he? Did he dumb? Did he do? - Mannfred Mann

Comment: @DanSmolinske That implication is in "Heir to the Empire" chapter 14 near page 164. They speculate that Yoda lived near the dark cave on Dagobah to hide his light-side force signature using the strong dark-side emanations there. "Just like a pair of positive and negative electric charges close enough together - to a distant observer they look almost like no charge at all."

Comment: @Octopus "There he was, just a-sitting in the swamp. Singing...". Can we copyright this before Weird Al Yankovic writes it?

Comment: @Axelrod: When 900 years old *you* reach, take lots of pharmaceuticals you will!

Comment: * do what, Yoda did?

Comment: Could be the same thing Obi-Wan did on Tatooine for twenty years.

Comment: @Octopus kept an eye on the child of his old friend to make sure that he was safe while he grew up?

Comment: @Octopus - my assumption was that Obi Wan was on Tatooine to keep an eye on Luke.

Comment: Yoda chose Dagobah because it was high on force (I believe I have watched it somewhere), so he was ofcourse interested in doing research on the Force.

Comment: We never saw the steamer trunk full of Twi'lek Monthly magazines, but it was there in the back of the hut.

Comment: The usual: stand on his head, stack rocks, etc.

Comment: good edit @user14111 - I considered doing the same

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> You have done well, but to succeed, your life must be spent learning, practicing.
>   ...
>   Now you see.
>   We have achieved what you seek and live between the realms.
>
> *(Destiny: Clone wars, Season 6, episode 12)*

> Now, does my training begin?
>
> The one you know as Qui-Gon Jinn will commune with you and guide your training.
>
> *(Sacrifice: Clone wars, Season 6, episode 13)*

Explain, the Priestesses did. Complete his trials Yoda did. Meditation, learning, practice -- spend time with these he must.

On Dagobah -- commune with the Force he did. Alive with the force Dagobah was. For communing and hiding, perfect. Idle he was not -- preparing he was. Something the Priestesses told him...

> Like us, you shall learn to maintain your consciousness after death.
>  Enlightenment, sprit, balance...
>  There is another Skywalker...

Comment: I hate to think that this is "canon" but...

Comment: @enderland ... but, it is.  `As of April 25, 2014, the only previously published materials that are considered canon are the six Star Wars films and the Star Wars: The Clone Wars television series` - from http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon

Comment: Based on scenes from the Rebels cartoon, it's possible he was also communing with other Jedi across the galaxy and giving them Force visions.

Answer (score 78):

**Aside from the needs of survival, spent his time studying the Force he did.**

From [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda/Canon):

> Using an E3-standard starship lifeboat, Yoda returned to Dagobah to begin his own exile. The lifeboat started to serve as Yoda's initial shelter, however, started to degrade within a year due to Dagobah's swampy environment. As the first shelter was slowly consumed by the swamp, Yoda **built a new home for himself**. He thus settled down to wait for the twins to grow up, and **continued his studies of the Force**.

To be fair, quite a lot of time it must have taken just to live in some degree of comfort. Building a home for himself no mean feat is, and finding food a non-negligible amount of time too must have consumed. But, in his spare time, with his studies keep up he did, keeping his mind active and his Force knowledge well-honed.

Comment: Coughdonkeycough.

Comment: downvote for being to close on rep

Comment: Upvote because it doesn't deserve a downvote, despite the donkey issue.

Comment: also it wasnt my downvote i duno who did it.

Comment: What is the actual canon source?

Comment: @randal'thor foiled agian

Comment: @WadCheber not sure if I'm just being thick, but what exactly is the "donkey issue"?

Comment: @Moogle - Rand hasn't seen Star Wars, so we made him ride a donkey backwards into the desert with a bucket on his head.

Comment: Feel bad for him, I do. Help from the Force, he may have had.

Comment: So it means, [this comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106339/on-dagobah-do-what-did-yoda#comment249451_106339) is right and he was mainly sitting there, waiting for the twins to become too old for being taught The Force (at least, according to the recommended practice)? At least, he’s in line with Obi Wan, telling that the fault was that Anakin was too old when starting the training and hence, waiting for Luke to become even older…

Comment: Two wrongs make a right maybe? :D

Comment: Agree with DVK, I do. Canon source missing, this is.

Comment: @DVK [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Chokhov) is my canon source :-)

Comment: So basically... "Built a castle in the swamp, I did.  Sank into the swamp, it did.  So, build a second one, I did.  Sank into the swamp, also that one did.  Build a third one, I did.  Burned down, fell over, then sank into the swamp, it did.  But the fourth one?  Stayed up, that one did!"

Comment: @randal'thor There's a difference between a canon source and a cannon source. :) That said, if I had to source a cannon, I think I'd go with a [GAU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAU-8_Avenger) or [G-range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AEDC_Range_G), depending on what I was trying to do. :)