# Is there more information on what Yoda did on Dagobah?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, history

His [Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda) and [databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/yoda) give *some* details on his housing situation and how he helped out a couple surviving Jedi, **but is there any story or series of stories that better explain the hardships of his exile**? Like how he kept sheltered after his lifeboat fell apart and then eventually built the house we see if the films, or how he figured out which plants/creatures were safe to eat and which were poisonous. Or even how he specifically dealt with the inner-conflict (and possible guilt) of the downfall of the Jedi Order. What about after Luke left to fight Vader? Did business simply return to usual for him?

There is [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/106339/75000) and subsequent answers which I first considered mine to be a dupe of, but they all seem silly and appear to not fully address the question in favor of nailing the perfect Yoda-ese. Plus it's over a year old and something new might have come out since then.

I'd prefer anything that explains it from Yoda's POV.

Please link any shops that sell whatever (if any) materials on this subject, as this is something that I would actually like to read about first hand.

Comment: Please don't intentionally create duplicates. If you don't like the answers on the dupe question, you can a) Post a bounty b) Use comments to address those who've already answered or c) Post your own answer.

Comment: Also, **shopping questions are off-topic** (when they're trivially simple to answer) and **recommendation questions are completely off-topic**.

Comment: Didn't know about the shopping thing. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Should this be marked for deletion then?

Comment: The general policy is to leave dupes un-deleted. They might help to signpost arrivals from google.

Comment: [Diffifult shopping questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/are-shopping-questions-on-topic) are moderately on-topic.

Comment: Okay. I was worried that any new input in the old question wouldn't be seen or taken seriously, as I mentioned in my question. But rules are rules. I'll look around myself a bit more.

Comment: We love new answers to old questions.

Comment: Well I'm looking to find an answer, not make one. :) Though if I do come across something, I'll be sure to share it.